# Function $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ exists

Tags: integration, analysis, functions

I want to know if there is a non-negative, unbounded function $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ exists.

Tried looking on Google, but it's difficult to search for integrals there, so I wasn't able to find anything, though I'm sure there are some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, there are plenty of them. By example
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}
\frac1{2\sqrt{x}},&x\in(0,1)\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$f(n)=n$ for $ n \in \mathbb N$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \in [0,\infty) \setminus \mathbb N.$

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1/\sqrt{x} - 3/\bigl(4 \sqrt{x_0}\bigr) &x \in (0,x_0] \\ 
x_0^{3/2}/(4x^2) & x \in (x_0,\infty)
\end{cases},\qquad x_0 \in \mathbb{R}_+=(0,\infty)
$$

Answer (score 0):

What if $f$ is defined as $n 1_{[1/n, 0]}$?

Comment: A bounded function? Or maybe $[1/n,0]= \varnothing$?